# Vue2 use @ alias in computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't seem to find anything stating a way to use the `@` src alias inside of a computed property. Is this possible?

I would like to dynamically assign an img src based on the component type. But computed property will only return back the literal string value.

```
computed: {
  dynamicImgSrc() {
    return '@/assets/icons/myImage.svg';
  }
}
```

Comment: `<img :src="require('@/assets/icons/myImage.svg')" />` also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[require](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)** for relative path imports in javascript

```
return require('@/assets/icons/myImage.svg')
```